# Bash script for deleting and inserting lines

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I need a script to disassemble and reconstruct a file, deleting a line somewhere in it, and inserting a few lines in its place.

So *A*) I need a command that selects everything before that line, but not that line, and nothing after that line, and *B*) I need one that selects everything after that line, but not that line, only after it...

Comment: How can that particular line be specified?

Comment: or some other way to edit a file, deleting one line somewhere in it, replacing it with a more then one line entry...

Comment: well you can read it with cat file.sh | grep line... but that reads the line, not text before it, or after it...

Comment: the line editor `sed` might be used if you identfy the line with its content or line number. `split`can be used if you identify the line with its line number. Maybe `sed` would be the best alternative.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Make the title resemble a question and reflect the content of the question.  Something similar to **bash script for inserting lines**.  This will make your question unique and easier to revisit and distinguish from other questions.  When it's resolved, it'll make it easy of other users with similar questions to find resolutions.

Comment: I can't really use line number, cause it's a shell script, and it can be edited in the future, I want the script to be able to edit it even after an update...

Comment: Then how do you know which line to replace? By searching for some words in it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) give us an example input file and the output you would expect from it and ii) explain why you would want to do this in the shell. it is possible, but much harder, slower and with awful syntax. There are much better tools to use than the shell. Are you open to solutions that are not pure shell?

Comment: ^ this! The procedure you suggest will be slow, if not impossible, if the file is huge. Better is to write per line to a new (temp?) file, replacing the line if it matches your criteria. That will be more efficient, since only the current line is in memory, then keeping large numbers of lines at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example using sed

The file `lines`:

```
line 1
line 2
line three
line 4
```

Script, that replaces the line with the content `line three` with three new lines:

```
sed  '/line three/ c\
This is a new line\nNext line\nLast new line' lines
```

where `\n` 'newline' separates the new lines.

Output:

```
line 1
line 2
This is a new line
Next line
Last new line
line 4
```

See this link for details about `sed`,

[www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: I needed to specify the -i option to actually edit the file instead of displaying it, but it worked...

Comment: I'm glad it works :-) Please tell us more about how you are using this script - How big is the file, that you are modifying and how do you identify the line to be replaced (and can you be sure that it will identify one and only one line)?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file named `in.txt` with the content:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

And you also have a file named `middle.txt`:

```
drei
trois
```

If you want to replace "three" in the first file with the content of the second file, you can write a something like this into a file `replace.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    if ($0 == "three") {
        file="middle.txt";
        while ((getline  0) {
            print;
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x replace.awk
```

And run it:

```
./replace.awk < in.txt
```

The result will be:

```
one
two
drei
trois
four
five
```

Comment: Note that your match will also insert the lines if the current line is, for example `twenty-three` or `one two three` or `foothree` or anything else matching three. It would be better to use `$1 == "three"` or, even better, `"$0 == "three"`.

Comment: You're right, @terdon. I fixed the condition, thanks!